# Qt - Adding data to a TableWidget via another TableWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qtablewidget

I am stuck on a certain problem with table widgets and I am in need of help. Basically, I am trying to get a table widget on a dialogue screen to get the information inside of it and then fill that information on to another table widget on a main window screen. So, when I click the OK button, it should take the text from one table widget and place it in the other table widget. I tried using the below code, and the build ran. But, as soon as I clicked OK, the program crashed. The table called `TableWidgetedit` is the table I am trying to copy from and send to the table in the mainwindow, named `tablewidget`. (just to make so I am not vague, I am trying to copy data from the one table and place it in another table, when a user clicks on the OK button.)

```
    int rows = 6;
    int columns = 5;
    Ui::MainWindow *mainui;
    void EditMode1::on_pushButton_clicked()
    {
       for (int i = 0; i<columns;++i){
           for (int j = 0;j<rows;++j){
             QTableWidgetItem *celltxt= TableWidgetedit.item(j,i);
             mainui->tableWidget->setItem(j,i,celltxt);
           }
        } 
    }
```

Any and all help is appreciated. Thank you!
(I am a not the best with Qt so if you don't mind explaining what changes you have made and why, that would a great help thank you!).

-UPDATE-
@Jeet here are the code for what im trying to do:

tablemainwindow1.h:

```
#ifndef TABLEMAINWINDOW1_H
#define TABLEMAINWINDOW1_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include "tabledialougewindow.h"

namespace Ui {
class TableMainWindow1;
}

class TableMainWindow1 : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit TableMainWindow1(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~TableMainWindow1();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::TableMainWindow1 *ui;
    TableDialougeWindow *tbl2;
};

#endif // TABLEMAINWINDOW1_H
```

tablemainwindow1.cpp:

```
#include "tablemainwindow1.h"
#include "ui_tablemainwindow1.h"

TableMainWindow1::TableMainWindow1(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::TableMainWindow1)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->tableWidget->setRowCount(3);
    ui->tableWidget->setColumnCount(3);
}

TableMainWindow1::~TableMainWindow1()
{
    delete ui;
}


void TableMainWindow1::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    tbl2 = new TableDialougeWindow(this);
    tbl2->show();
}
```

tabledialougewindow.h:

```
#ifndef TABLEDIALOUGEWINDOW_H
#define TABLEDIALOUGEWINDOW_H

#include <QDialog>

namespace Ui {
class TableDialougeWindow;
}

class TableDialougeWindow : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit TableDialougeWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~TableDialougeWindow();

private slots:
    void on_buttonBox_accepted();

private:
    Ui::TableDialougeWindow *ui;
};

#endif // TABLEDIALOUGEWINDOW_H
```

tabledialougewindow.cpp:

```
#include "tabledialougewindow.h"
#include "ui_tabledialougewindow.h"
#include "tablemainwindow1.h"
#include "ui_tablemainwindow1.h"

int Rows = 3;
int Columns = 3;
Ui::TableMainWindow1 *mainui;
TableDialougeWindow::TableDialougeWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::TableDialougeWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->tableWidget->setRowCount(Rows);
    ui->tableWidget->setColumnCount(Columns);
}

TableDialougeWindow::~TableDialougeWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}


void TableDialougeWindow::on_buttonBox_accepted()
{
    for(int i = 0;i<Columns;++i){
        for(int j = 0;j<Rows;++j){
            QTableWidgetItem *celltxt = ui->tableWidget->item(j,i);
            QTableWidgetItem *celltxt2 =new QTableWidgetItem(*celltxt);
            mainui->tableWidget->setItem(j,i,celltxt2);
        }
    }
    accept();
}
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is we cannot insert an item that is already owned by another QTableWidget. So before make a copy we need to clone the data. we can use copy constructor to achieve this. Code comment will explain in detail. Hope this help.

```
    void MainWindow::on_cmdTransfer_clicked()
{
    //Source Table
    int rows = ui->tbl1->rowCount();
    int columns =ui->tbl1->columnCount();

    //Destination Table
    ui->tbl2->setColumnCount(columns);
    ui->tbl2->setRowCount(rows);

   //Copy data form one table to another.
   for (int i = 0; i<columns;++i){
       for (int j = 0;j<rows;++j){
         QTableWidgetItem *celltxt= ui->tbl1->item(j,i);
         //Clone the data using copy constructor
         QTableWidgetItem *celltxt1=new QTableWidgetItem(*celltxt);
         ui->tbl2->setItem(j,i,celltxt1);
       }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow thank you so much! I was trying to think of copying and pasting it but was not too sure on how too do it with qt, thank you so much!

Comment: -UPDATE-
I tried inputting this code, but my program still crashes (and when i say crashes, i mean it compiles and runs the program, but when i click on the button to copy from one table to another it just says "Program.exe has stopped working"). Is it because one table is on a mainwindow screen and the other table is in a dialogue screen?

Comment: @KittyBurner, Without seeing you class (Mainwindow  & Dialog) structure, it is tough to say how to refer the object from one to another.

Comment: okay, can you tell me what exactly you want to see? cause when you say without seeing my class structure, im not sure exactly what part you are referring too.

Comment: Is it possible to you to create and share a small implementation of your both the classes with the qtable(static) data, which gives error on copy? If so i can try from my side to find and rectify the error.

Comment: the code above is a copy of my code. I hope that will do.

Comment: let me try i and get back

Comment: @KittyBurner. 1) You referred both the header file in both classes so your main window class need forward declaration for the dialog window. 2) "mainui->tableWidget->setItem(j,i,celltxt2);" you can't access tableWidget with out the variable "ui". And also it is private in mainwindow class. So i hope, now you got some idea to correct your code.

Comment: i havent looked at this too much but i cant really get the idea of what you are saying, please elaborate because im not sure what you mean. i have put a foward declerartion in my dialog window, "Ui::TableMainWindow1 *mainui;" and then i go on to access the other table widget with the use of mainui which uses the variable ui. please xplain or give me an example of what to do.